# Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "Brot und Butter"?

Tags: meaning, idiom, standard-german

> Arbeiten mit HTML, CSS und JavaScript **sind dein Brot und Butter**

Was ist die Bedeutung von **Brot und Butter**. Ist es eine Redewendung? Auch im Internet konnte ich nichts darüber finden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brot und Butter sind die grundlegenden Mahlzeiten, als Frühstück der Start in den Tag und zum Abendessen der Abschluss des Tages. Es ist also etwas alltägliches, mit dem du sehr vertraut bist. In diesem Falle bedeutet es, dass Du dich bestens mit den oben genannten Scriptsprachen auskennst.

Tatsächlich ist es wohl einfach eine wörtliche Übersetzung vom englischen [bread and butter](https://m.dict.cc/deen/?s=bread%20and%20butter)

edit: Wie PiedPiper in den Kommentaren angemerkt hat, gibt es das deutsche Equivalent dazu: **... sind dein täglich Brot**

Comment: Sicher, dass es eine Übersetzung aus dem Englischen ist?

Comment: @stephanmg Als Redewendung ist "Bread and butter" weitverbreitet, "Brot und Butter" habe ich noch nie gehört. Eine bessere Übersetzung wäre "das ist dein tägliches Brot"

Comment: PiedPiper: Wirklich? Mir sind beide Begriffe sowohl in den USA als auch im deutschsprachigen Raum oft begegnet. Seltsam. Aber ich denke ich kann dir zustimmen - Das ist vielleicht nur meine persönliche Erfahrung.

Comment: Und "Mit ... zu arbeiten ist Dein täglich Brot". "Arbeiten ... sind" klingt sehr nach Hausarbeiten.

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher ob ich das im Deutschen schon gehört habe, aber das wäre ja nicht das erste mal dass ein englischer Ausdruck wörtlich übersetzt übernommen wird und sich dann einbürgert.
Bei "bread and butter" müsste man noch darauf achten, dass es sowohl alltäglich bedeutet als auch Brotverdienst o.ä.  Hier käme es also auf den Kontext an wie das genau gemeint ist, "täglich Brot" passt aber gut, das Geldverdienen wird nicht besonders betont.

Comment: @infinitezero Nur am Rande: HTML und Css sind keine Scriptsprachen.

Comment: Ich hab's der Einfachheit halber zu Scriptsprachen zusammengefasst, weil's erst recht keine Programmiersprachen sind. Wenn Du darauf bestehst, editiere ich es gerne genauer.

Comment: Die Herkunft aus dem Englischen ist plausibel. Ins Deutschen fand die Redewendung vermutlich in den 1980-er Jahren Eingang. Beispiele: [Brot-und-Butter-Geschäft](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~das%20Brot%20und%20Buttergesch%C3%A4ft&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou), [Brot-und-Butter-Themen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brot).

Answer (score 2):

Mir ging es genau so ... aber im englischen ist es tatsächlich ein feste Redewendung: da sind es die Aktivitäten, die Sekunden, Minuten und Jahre, die du für deinen Broterwerb "opferst". Wenn du einen Job hast, der dich nicht nur zu 100% ausfüllt, sondern auch "erfüllt", dann bist du dem Glück einen Schritt näher. :-)